# Spring Security get custom headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to receive a custom header Date in my application. Below is my code

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/data/**").authenticated().and()
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Code to get the header

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Enumeration<String> ss = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (ss.hasMoreElements()) {
        String string = (String) ss.nextElement();
        System.out.println(string);
    }
    System.out.println(request.getDateHeader("date"));

}
```

Output:

```
host
connection
content-length
accept
origin
x-requested-with
user-agent
content-type
referer
accept-encoding
accept-language
cookie
-1
```

Request:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2019 13:46:52 GMT' {"type":"formData"} 'http://localhost:8080/data'
```

I want to receive the date header I am passing, but did't get it. What is blocking the extra header?

Comment: Works for me with your date as formatted your way using an `HttpServletRequest` object injected into a REST controller method. Didn't try a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue with the header name as it could be the reserved key

> Date

Try with some other random header name and check if that works.